# rails form_for how to save in another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I want to create an ec site and try to make quantity system.

What I want to do: Adding a item in quantity of CreateBasketItems(2021_create_basket_items.rb)

Question: How can I write some code in item/show.html.erb which is part of form_with() in particular?

2021_create_basket_items.rb

```
class CreateBasketItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
      def change
        create_table :basket_items do |t|
          t.references :basket, index: true, null: false, foreign_key: true
          t.references :item, index: true, null: false, foreign_key: true
          t.integer    :quantity, null: false, default: 1
          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```

item/show.html.erb

```
The url:  show.html.erb => item_controller.rb/create

<%= form_for url: item_add_to_baskets_path(@item,@basket_item), method: :post do |f| %>
　　<%= f.select :quantity,[1,2,3], id: "country1", class: "frm-field required sect" %>
   <%= f.submit "add to basket", class: "item_add" %> 
<% end %>
```

just in case the error is.

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):
```

item_controller.rb

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  # before_action :authenticate_user!
  def show
    basket = current_user.prepare_basket
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @basket_item = basket.basket_items(params[:quantity])
  end
  
  def index
    # if(params[:category])
    #   @items = Item.where(category: params[:category]).paginate(page: params[:page])
    # else
    #   @items = Item.paginate(page: params[:page])
    # end
    @items = (params[:category]) ? Item.where(category: params[:category]).paginate(page: params[:page]) :
    Item.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
end
```

add_to_basket_controller.rb

```
class Items::AddToBasketsController < Items::ApplicationController
  def create
    basket = current_user.prepare_basket
    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
    @basket_item = basket.basket_items(params[:quantity])
    basket.basket_items.create!(item_id: @item.id, quantity: @basket_item)
    flash[:success] = "your item in basket"
    redirect_to baskets_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it would be good to see your routes as well, but I'm guessing you've got the form pointing to the url that matches the `Items::AddToBasketsController#create` action. From what you've shared, it looks like you've got a couple things in the controller that are part of the issue. You'll want to create a backet_item that has the quantity, refers to a basket and an item. One thing you could do is store the current_user's active basket id in the session And then have a method like `current_basket` that will retrieve the `current_user`'s active basket.

```
def current_basket
  if session[:active_basket_id]
    @current_basket = current_user.baskets.find_by_id(session[:active_basket_id])
  else
    @current_basket = current_user.prepare_basket
    session[:active_basket_id] = @current_basket.id
  end
  @current_basket
end
```

At that point, all you'd need would be to be able to submit the item_id and the quantity though params. If you wanna keep things RESTful, you could have a route like this:

```
post '/basket_items', to: 'Items::AddToBasketsController#create'
```

and then in the controller, you'd also need to have strong parameters:

```
def basket_item_params
  params.require(:basket_item).permit(:item_id, :quantity)
end
```

And you'd need to update the create action to work something like this:

```
def create
  current_basket.basket_items.create!(basket_item_params) 
  flash[:success] = "your item in basket"
  redirect_to baskets_path
end
```

`current_basket.basket_items.create!(basket_item_params)` will assign the `basket_id` automatically because we build the basket_item on its association with `current_basket`. This method comes from `has_many :basket_items` in the `Basket` class. You can read more about [all the association methods you get from `has_many` on APIDock](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many).

And finally the form would have a hidden field for the item_id in addition to the quantity. The basket could come from the session (that way you can add multiple items to the same basket as you switch from one page to another. The form would look more like this:

```
<%= form_with model: @item.basket_items.build, method: :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :item_id %>
  <%= f.select :quantity,[1,2,3], id: "country1", class: "frm-field required sect" %>
  <%= f.submit "add to basket", class: "item_add" %> 
<% end %>
```

Building the `basket_item` with `@item.basket_items.build` will automatically assign its item_id, so it will be populated as the value in the hidden field and passed along with params when you submit the form.

Comment: It could solved this. Thank you so much!!